# Find size of a blank CD

Tags: dvd, cd

I can't `mount` a DVD or CD if it is blank, but I'd like to find out its size before.

With a USB I could easily use `fdisk`, but that doesn't work with CD or DVD

If possible I'd also like to find out whether it's a DVD or CD. `sr0` is the listed block device.

Answer (score 7):

You can  do this with [udftools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/udftools)

```
cdrwtool -i -d /dev/sr0 | awk '$1 == "free_blocks" {print $3 * 2048}'
```

will show the size in bytes.

On an empty DVD I get

```
4.70037e+09
```

and it says 4.7Gb on the disc itself.

---

> If possible i'd also like to find out whether it's dvd or cd.

There are no 4.7Gb cd's. Nor 700Mb dvd's. The size also shows you what kind of medium it is.

---

There is also

```
cdrecord -minfo -v
```

To use it install:

```
sudo apt install wodim
```

---

There is also [dvd+rw-mediainfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/xenial/dvd+rw-tools):

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0
```

Comment: wodim 9:1.1.11-2ubuntu3 shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not like the command `cdrecord -minfo -v` and returns a message `wodim: Bad Option: -minfo`

Comment: dvd+rw-mediainfo: :-( non-DVD media mounted, exiting...